# Not show correct delta in minutes

Tags: postgresql-9.5

column **created_at** type **timestamp** without timezone.

I need to get delta in minutes between current date and column **created_at**

Query:

```
select id, created_at,
extract(minutes from (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - created_at) as delta
from shop_order order by created_at
```

And here result:

[image]

Why in record with id = 20 the delta is 19 ?

It's difference is **3 DAYS**. Why show only 19 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interval (which is the result of subtracting two timestamp) consists of several "parts" (similar to a `date`) and `extract` only extracts the named part, not the representation of that interval for that unit. If the result of the subtraction is e.g. `3 days 19 minutes` extract will return 19 minutes - similar to the way `extract(year ...)` or `extract(month ...)` work.

You can extract the number of seconds and then divide that by 60 to get the total duration in minutes:

```
select id, 
       created_at,
       extract(epoch from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - created_at) / 60 as delta
from shop_order order 
by created_at
```

Comment: Why I need to use "epoch" (1970) to get delta?

Comment: @a_subscriber: As I have written: `epoch` extras the number of seconds from the result of `current_timestamp - created_at`